# Java Parsing website

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

I am trying to parse and get some specific links from a given website. I have checked a lot of questions here regarding jsoup, and tried the ones that could be the solution but I didn't succeed, I have started to think that maybe the website I am trying to parse is some specific one. Here is one chunk of the HTML, where I want to get all the links from all the article classes in the HTML:

```
<article id="item_65190842" class="media item_row ptm pbm nmt" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">  
<a title="Flera bilder" itemprop="url" tabindex="50" href="http://www.blocket.se/vastmanland/Volkswagen_Passat_2_0_TDI_DSG_140_Hk_Sportlin_65190842.htm?ca=11&w=3" class="pull-left item-link nohistory image_container  has_multiple_images" data-js="item_link"><ul class="object-attribute-badges"></ul><img src="https://cdn.blocket.com/static/0/lithumbs/41/4164545596.jpg" title="Flera bilder" alt="Flera bilder" width="169px" height="126px" class="item_image"/></a>

<div class="media-body desc" itemprop="itemOffered" itemscope><header class="clearfix"><div class="pull-left "><a class="label label-default mrxs" itemprop="url" onclick="return xt_click(this,'C','11','Butiksbadge','N')" href="http://www.blocket.se/bildepan-i-morgongava?ca=11">Butik</a>Västmanland</div><time datetime="2016-02-10 13:47:01" pubdate itemprop="datePublished" class="pull-right">Idag  13:47</time></header><h1 class="h5 media-heading ptxs" itemprop="name"><a href="http://www.blocket.se/vastmanland/Volkswagen_Passat_2_0_TDI_DSG_140_Hk_Sportlin_65190842.htm?ca=11&w=3" title="Volkswagen Passat 2.0 TDI DSG 140 Hk Sportlin" itemprop="url" tabindex="50" class="item_link">Volkswagen Passat 2.0 TDI DSG 140 Hk Sportlin -08</a></h1><p itemprop="price" class="list_price font-large">62 900:-</p><footer><div class="pull-right addon"></div></footer></div>
</article>
```

I want to get the link inside the `<a title="Flera bilder"`

Here is the web page that I want to parse

http://www.blocket.se/hela_sverige/bilar/

Comment: you have a empty link

Comment: its fixed now I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the `Document` object using Jsoup. This is what you need.

```
Elements links = doc.select("a[title=Flera bilder]")
for(Element link : links){
    //This is the absolute link that you need. 
    String absHref = link.attr("abs:href");
}
```

Refer to Jsoup [cookbook](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/working-with-urls) for further reference

Comment: it worked !!! Thank you dude

Comment: No problem. Beware that if there is anything loaded through Javascript. Jsoup won't work